# Undefined symbols for architecture initcscr

Tags: c++, xcode, ncurses

So I was writing code for a clear screen function.  Everything I had found said to use curse library functions to do this, but I ran into a problem when I had to use `initscr()` The given error was as follows:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_initscr", referenced from:
      _main in TheGame...I think.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

As far as I can tell the last two lines are a reference to a different error, so if anyone know what that is that would be great.
The current code that is throwing an error is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curses.h>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main(void){
    //Initializations
    initscr();
    srand(static_cast<int>(time(0)));

    menu();

    return 0;
}
```

I do know that using namespace std is bad practice, but that is what my book told me to do, menu references a while loop that spreads to other functions by user input that worked perfectly before `curses.h` and `initscr()` I have tried putting `void` and all numbers between 1 and 10 in the parenthesis.  Void throws a Parse Issue (`Expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction`) while the numbers all threw `No matching function for call to 'initscr'`

using the recommended `*initscr();` throws the same error as just plain `initscr()`

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: I doubt that `using namespace std;` is the cause of error here. Looks like your ncurses library was built with a c compiler, and your're missing a `extern "C" { }` wrapping around the `#include <curses.h>`.

Comment: Is there a way to fix this or should I try to find a totally different way of `clrscr`?

Comment: Did you already check [this Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix). Sounds like you're barking up the wrong tree here.

Comment: So, I read that but it doesn't answer my question, "What do I do to fix it?"  I think I understand what is wrong, but I really don't understand what to do about it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile and link your program to ncurses: `g++ -lncurses <source code>`

Your program will probably work now.